# No internet connection in my Flutter website in release mode

Tags: flutter, dart, http

i made website in Flutter. In debug mode my website does API calls without problem,
but in release mode is acting like there is no connection at all.

I know `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` solve problem in Android but what about web?

Dependencies:

`get: ^4.3.8  http: ^0.13.4`

environment:
`sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"`

API call :

```
  var client = http.Client();

  var uri = Uri.parse("https://********");
  var response = await client.get(uri, headers: {
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": "**************"
  });
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var json = response.body;

    return postFromJson(json);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the issue.

Flexible was inside Padding